# How to set utf-8 to csvtojscon?

Tags: json, csv, utf-8

I want to extract the data from csv file, for that I am using csvtojson npm , it is working fine but if the csv file contains any foregin letters then it return  "��" in my json so can anyone guide me here

```
var converter  = require("csvtojson");

    function(req, data){
    var array = [];
    var json = await convert().fromFile(filepath.csv);
    array.push(json)
    // continuation of my code here
    }
```

Comment: Is the csv file actually saved in UTF-8 encoding? (check with Notepad++ or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var converter  = require("csvtojson");
var json = await convert().fromFile(filepath.csv,{  encoding: 'binary' });
```